# How to handle multiple web requests in one view controller?

Tags: ios, web-services, asynchronous

I have read many questions regarding handling multiple requests asynchronously in one view controller. But, what I'm really looking is, what is the best practice to handle multiple web requests efficiently?All those requests are independent to each other. Is it a best practice to handle couple of those web requests in init method and rest in viewdidload method?

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: these request are dependent on each other or independent?

Comment: all the requests are independent.

Comment: in that case you can handle web requests any where because they are independent and can be called anywhere in viewcontroller... they will not affect app performance

Comment: What if it is dependent?

Comment: I've heard good things about something called PromiseKit. Take a look and see if it helps you somehow: http://promisekit.org/

Comment: @manecosta... they don't have much work on good practices. Anyways, it might help to kickstart on what i'm looking for.